# How do I evaluate statistical significance of a small dataset compared to a larger one? Selection issues

Tags: statistical-significance

I have 5 groups on data, essentially intervals of ages (with number of samples in brackets):

```
1) 15 - 20 yrs old (59)
2) 20 - 25 yrs old (40)
3) 25 - 30 yrs old (54)
4) 30 - 35 yrs old (43)
5) 35 - 40 yrs old (21)
```

The quantity of samples of each group are different, and I am required to conduct analysis into each group, per se. However, considering group 5 `(35 - 40 yrs old)` has only 21 samples, I am inclined to leave this group out. Is there a statistical way for me to check if this group should be left out? What methods are there?

Comment: What analysis are you planning to do with each group?

Comment: Just some histogram analysis and some simple correlation assessment

Comment: @Corse if it is just for histograms and bivariate correlations then what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you calculate your correlations in each group and then add confidence intervals. The groups with larger samples will have narrower intervals than the groups with smaller samples, indicating that the correlation estimates in the former groups are more precise. For histograms, there's no issue in including all groups since this is a purely descriptive exercise.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any 'threshold' for confidence values that allows me to remove a particular group if the confidence range is too large?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. It's not like you say "the correlation is X with Y% confidence." Rather, you say that "plausible values for the correlation are in the interval of X plus or minus Y." With more samples, that Y value will be smaller so we can be more precise about the range of values that the correlation might take on. In a large group, your interval might be between .50 and .60, whereas in a small group, your interval might be between .30 and .80. See the difference? Also, you seem intent on "removing" the small group. Can you explain why this is so important to you?

Comment: I see. That clears things up. Actually I am intent to remove group 5 primarily because it only consists of 21 samples (<30). So I would pre-suppose it is not a 'large' dataset (in the conventional definition of large, N >= 30) and results might not be very reflective in that case.

Comment: It's good to be mindful of the importance of sample size. However, decomposing it into a yes-no dichotomy of ">30=good" and "<30=bad" is too restrictive. It is precisely because of its impact on the precision of an estimate (e.g., a correlation) that sample size is important. It is true that samples larger than 30 will yield more precise estimates than samples smaller than 30, but they are not above reproach. And samples smaller than 30 are not without informative value. Rather than dichotomize this, quantify it. Show the precision of each estimate using confidence intervals.

Comment: that is concise and insightful. i will use confidence intervals as indicative. thank you very much